# Select * from filled table returns unexpected result in InfluxDB

Tags: select, influxdb

I have a setup with an InfluxDB instance that regularly gets values inserted into. When I run the following query in the InfluxDB Administration Interface, it returns `30000`:

```
select count(values) from my_table
```

When I run this query, though, it says, that there are no results:

```
select * from my_table
```

I can remember, though, that this query used to work, when there were less values in there. Is this a known and normal behavior or am I missing something?

Comment: What happens when you issue the query using `curl` or via the `InfluxDB CLI`?